# MYSQL: in having use IF

Tags: mysql

My MYSQL having query (car_level_id came from SELECT CASE):

```
HAVING (CASE WHEN car_level_id = "1" THEN c.status != "2" END)
```

I need ignore cars only with level 1 and status 2.

Basically i need just simple IF statement, but this not working.

Comment: Show us the  table with some example data and your complete query then we can help you better.... "I need ignore cars only with level 1 and status 2." this is possible with ...`WHERE car_level_id != "1" OR c.status != "2"`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN car_level_id = "1" AND c.status = "2" END) = 0
```

This will filter out groups having at least one record with `car_level_id = "1"` and `c.status = "2"`.